# How to get innerHTML value with JavaScript in Asp.net Core 5 View

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First of all, I apologize for writing English, which may not be correct.

In the Asp.Net Core project view, I want innerHTML to capture multiple Span tags, each represented by a loop, using JavaScript and display the sum of them in another tag.
But I can only get the value of one tag with a specific name or ID and I can not get the value of innerHTML from multiple tags with one name.

Thank you for your guidance

Loop in elements Table:

```
@foreach (var R in Model.Where(x => x.ReportRDId == show.ReportRDId))
 {
     <tr>
         <td>
         <span>@R.CourseName</span>
          +
         <span>@R.SectionName</span>
          +
         <span name="test-@R.ReportDayName">@R.TestCount <span>تست </span>  </span>
          +
         <span >@R.TimeCount <span>ساعت </span>  </span>
         </td>

      </tr>


    }
```

I tried to make the name of each tag unique by using a value obtained from the loop
The name of each tag is correct, but I can not read the name correctly in JavaScript

My JavaScript Code :

```
    @foreach (var R in Model.GroupBy(x => x.ReportRDId).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()))
    {
      <script>

               //To display the sum of the tests

               var Total = document.getElementsByName("TotalTest-@R.ReportDayName");

               //Tests innerHTML

               var test = document.querySelectorAll("[name='test-@R.ReportDayName']");

               //loop in test variable

               var count = 0;
               console.log(test);
               test.forEach(e => {

               console.log(e.innerHTML);
               count += parseInt(e.innerHTML);
               Total.forEach(element => {
               element.innerHTML = count;
                  });
              });

        </script>
      }
```

I did these things but the result I got was wrong

Browser Inspect view for one of the tags (Pay attention to the value of its name):

```
<script>

//To display the sum of the tests

var Total = document.getElementsByName("TotalTest-&#x634;&#x646;&#x628;&#x647;");

//Tests innerHTML

var test = document.querySelectorAll("[name='test-&#x634;&#x646;&#x628;&#x647;']");

//loop in test variable

var count = 0;
console.log(test);
test.forEach(e => {

    console.log(e.innerHTML);
    count += parseInt(e.innerHTML);
    Total.forEach(element => {
        element.innerHTML = count;
    });
});
```

Comment: `name` is a custom attribute for `span` elements, `document.querySelectorAll` should work, but `gEBN` doesn't.

Comment: @Teemu Unfortunately, I did not understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem
My mistake was to use only @ R.ReportDayName instead of @ Html.Raw (@ R.ReportDayName).

The correct solution (Attention to @Html.Raw(@R.ReportDayName) ):

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(x => x.ReportRDId).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Take(1))
    {
        <text>
        
        //To display the sum of the tests
        var Total = document.getElementsByName("TotalTest-@Html.Raw(R.ReportDayName)");
        //Tests innerHTML
        var test = document.querySelectorAll("[name='test-@Html.Raw(R.ReportDayName)']");
        //loop in test variable
        var count = 0;
        console.log(test);
        test.forEach(e =>
        {

            console.log(e.innerHTML);
            count += parseInt(e.innerHTML);
            Total.forEach(element =>
            {
                element.innerHTML = count;
            });
        });
        </text>
    }
```